# R: N-Queens finding the Diagonal

Tags: r, chess, n-queens, chessboard.js

Made a post earlier today expressing I was trying to find a solution to the N-Queens problem. The first part of this is determining the following function:

```
>safe(chess.piece,chess.board)
```

Where:

```
>chess.board <- matrix(0,8,8)
>chess.board[r,c] <- 1 #1 represents the queen which can be placed in any row/column on the board
>chess.piece <- c(x,x) #basically and row/column value I choose in the 8x8 matrix
```

Currently I have the following code for the horizontal and vertical planes:

```
>safe <- function(a,b){
  if((sum(b[a[1],])<1) & (sum(b[,a[2]])<1))
  {return(TRUE)
  }else{
    return(FALSE)
  }
}
```

Basically works on summing the rows/columns and checking if greater (FALSE) or equal (TRUE) to 0. But how in the world do I find the diagonal sum of the chess.board matrix based on the rows/columns determined by the chess.piece ?! I am ripping my hair out over this as I am decently new to R but I need a solution and just can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance, J.S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to write a couple of functions to extract partial diagonals from a square matrix, using the fact that you can use 1-dimensional indexing since matrices are just vectors under the hood and these diagonals correspond to certain arithmetical sequences of indices:

```
udiag <- function(A,i,j){
  n <- nrow(A)
  a <- i + n*(j-1) - (n-1)*min(n-i,j-1)
  b <- i + n*(j-1) + (n-1)*min(i-1,n-j)
  A[seq(a,b,n-1)]
}

ddiag <- function(A,i,j){
  n <- nrow(A)
  a <- i + n*(j-1) - (n+1)*min(i-1,j-1)
  b <- i + n*(j-1) + (n+1)*min(n-i,n-j)
  A[seq(a,b,n+1)]
}
```

These two functions extract the upward slanting and downward slanting diagonals respectively. You can use these two functions and write your `safe` like this:

```
safe <- function(x,y){
  i <- x[1]
  j <- x[2]
  sum(y[i,]) == 0 & sum(y[,j]) == 0 & sum(udiag(y,i,j)) == 0 & sum(ddiag(y,i,j)) == 0
}
```

**On Edit:** In view of the intended application, I wrote `udiag()` and `ddiag()` to work with square matrices only. Since they may have other uses in potentially nonsquare matrices, they can be easily modified to handle such cases:

```
udiag <- function(A,i,j){
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  a <- i + m*(j-1) - (m-1)*min(m-i,j-1)
  b <- i + m*(j-1) + (m-1)*min(i-1,n-j)
  A[seq(a,b,m-1)]
}

ddiag <- function(A,i,j){
  m <- nrow(A)
  n <- ncol(A)
  a <- i + m*(j-1) - (m+1)*min(i-1,j-1)
  b <- i + m*(j-1) + (m+1)*min(m-i,n-j)
  A[seq(a,b,m+1)]
}
```

For example:

```
> A <- matrix(1:12,nrow = 3)
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> udiag(A,2,3)
[1]  6  8 10
> ddiag(A,2,3)
[1]  4  8 12
```

Comment: Your a life saver John. Great work! Think I got so frustrated by it I never really considered developing other functions to help me solve the problem! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Consider you have to check if board element (x,y) can be attacked from any diagonal element or not. (x,y) can be attacked diagonally if any element lying on its diagonal element is a queen.Assume (p,q) is board element having a queen.Now condition for element(x,y) to lie on diagonal coordinates of board element (p,q) would be p+q == x+y or p-q == x-y .This can also be interpreted as the condition for elements (p,q) and (x,y) to lie on same diagonal.So, if there is queen at (p,q) and we have to check whether (x,y) can be attacked by this queen or not, the condition for this would be:-

```
            if((board[p][q] == 1 ) && ((p+q == x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true; 
            }
```

Complete function for checking if element at (x,y) i.e., board[x,y] is attacked by diagonal elements or not would be:-

```
for(int p=1;p<board.length;p++){
        for(int q=1;q<board.length;q++){

            if(p==x && q==y){   //skipping check if element under consideration is same
                continue;
            }

            if((board[p][q] == 1 )&& ((p+q == x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Complete function for checking if element (x,y) is attacked or not would be:-

```
    public static boolean is_attacked(int x,int y,int board[][],int n){
    for(int i = 1;i < board.length;i++){
        if(board[x][i] == 1){            //if any cell in xth row is 1 i.e.,queen is there in that row
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1;i < board.length;i++){     
        if(board[i][y] == 1){         //if any cell in yth column is 1 i.e.,queen is there in that column
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int p=1;p<board.length;p++){
        for(int q=1;q<board.length;q++){

            if(p==x && q==y){
                continue;
            }

            if((board[p][q]== 1 )&& ((p+q== x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!